# Is it always possible to destroy a non-special Aronszajn tree with c.c.c. forcing?

Tags: set-theory

Aronszajn trees are trees with $\omega_1$ levels and each of their levels and branches is countable. Special trees are trees that equal to a countable union of their antichains.
Suslin trees are c.c.c. Aronszajn trees. By destroying a Aronszajn tree I mean forcing to add a $\aleph_1$ branch.

It is obvious that Suslin trees can be c.c.c. forced to have a new branch, while special Aronszajn trees cannot be destroyed by c.c.c. forcing.

The question is: is it always possible to destroy a non-special Aronszajn tree with c.c.c. forcing?

Comment: In other words, "is every non-special Aronszajn tree Suslin?" (Consistently, per tree, no, take the disjoint union of a Suslin tree and a special Aronszajn tree with a new root; it's not special and it's not Suslin; but we can force with the Suslin part to destroy it.)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162657/does-every-aronszajn-tree-has-a-suslin-or-a-special-subtree https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316582/destroying-suslin-nothing-special

Comment: (Note that this is really the rephrased version I wrote above, since if $\Bbb P$ added a branch to the Aronszajn tree, then the Aronszajn tree completely embeds into $\Bbb P$, in the sense of forcing, and therefore must be ccc. In other words, it has to be Suslin.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't get it. Isn't the tree you mentioned in the first comment a counterexample to your third comment?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's more subtle than that. It's really asking if every non-special Aronszajn tree has a Suslin *subtree*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila With regard to that question you posted, is it possible to make a Suslin tree no longer Suslin but still non-special Aronszajn with c.c.c. forcing? I'm not familiar with Shelah's work, but It seems the forcing he used is not c.c.c..

Comment: You can again arrange for this sort of trivialities, take the sum of two Suslin trees that are incomparable in the order-embedding order; then specialise one of them. So you really want to say that you're not specialising any subtree. My answer to that is that it's a good question, and I don't have an answer.